# jQuery: select all internal links EXCLUDING links to downloadable files

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, internal

I'm using following piece of jQuery code to select all internal links ...

```
var siteURL = "http://" + top.location.host.toString();
var $internalLinks = $("a[href^='"+siteURL+"'], a[href^='/'], a[href^='./'], a[href^='../'], a[href^='#']");
```

and it works just fine. The only problem i'm facing is that i don't want to select internal links which directly points to downloadable files (e.g. http://www.example.com/downloadable.pdf)

Extension could be anything (pdf, mp3, jpg, gif, webm ... etc)

Now question is, how to exclude such internal links from the above criteria?

Or if i use .not() function to exclude such links, question would be, how to select all internal links which directly points to such downloadable files?

Comment: Any URL can return any kind of data. You cannot tell what kind of file will be served up by a URL. A URL like `http://www.example.com/123` might return HTML or MP3 or JPEG data, and a URL like `http://www.example.com/me.html` might return a PDF. The file extension is a convention only. The question, ask you've asked it, isn't really answerable. You should update it to reflect that you're looking for a generic way of excluding URLs with specific file extensions.

Comment: @meagar you are right, question is updated now.

Comment: Any file is downloadable. That's how you are able to view it in your browser or save the file to your desktop. There's no automatic way to do this; you have to define the extensions yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple solution would be to use a `filter` or `not` with a regular expression to reject the links you don't want:

```
var $internalLinks = $("a[href^='"+siteURL+"'], a[href^='/'], a[href^='./'], a[href^='../'], a[href^='#']");

$internalLinks = $internalLinks.not(function () {
  return $(this).attr('href').match(/\.(pdf|mp3|jpg|jpeg|etc)$/i);
});
```

The opposite, assuming all of your "not downloadable" URLs end in `.html` or `.htm`, would be to `filter` for links with those extensions:

```
$internalLinks = $internalLinks.filter(function () {
  return $(this).attr('href').match(/\.html?/);
});
```

Comment: cannot i automate the process to filter out all internal links ending with ANY downloadable file extension, without defining the extensions manually?

Comment: No, because there is no such thing as a "downloadable extension". You need to either explicitly whitelist the extensions you want (.htm and .html for example), or explicitly blacklist the extensions you don't want. There is no way to do this automatically.

Comment: So is there any way to select all internal links ending with ANY file extension, whether its .html or .pdf? because in this case it would be much easier to whitelist a few extensions (e.g. .html, .php ... etc) afterwards instead of manually blacklisting each extension.

Comment: What about links like `/users/joe-bob`?

Comment: Well, now i understand the issue. Thanks man, being too tired, i should have a sleep now. I'm accepting your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You can chain a `.not()` method to your selection and use the ends with selector. E.g.

```
$("a[href^=something]").not("[href$=pdf]")
```

http://api.jquery.com/not/

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/

Working jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/uPps6/

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of filetypes in use, you could use .not. Untested:

```
$internalLinks = $internalLinks.not($('a[href$=".mp3"]')...
```

Comment: I may use such method, but i'll have to manually define all extensions in this case. I want some better approach here, which should not include defining each file extension manually.